# Docker's healthcheck on Windows container and exit code ("||" linux equivalent)

Tags: windows, powershell, curl, docker

I would like to do something like this in a Dockerfile for windows:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s \
            --timeout=5s \
            CMD C:\\src\\curl.exe -f http://127.0.0.1:8080/health; if($LastExitCode) {$LastExitCode=1}
```

The command itself seems to be fine. Exit code is changed to 1 whenever curl returns something different than 0. The problem appears when I try to define it in a Dockerfile. When Docker runs it I got following output in inspect:

```
(6) Couldn't resolve host 'if($LastExitCode)'\r\ncurl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '$LastExitCode=1'\r\n"
```

So basically he treats everything after semicolon as an argument of curl. Any idea how can I tackle this? I know I can write a script and put it inside container, but I'd rather not do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally solved it! In case someone else needs, here is a solution that worked for me:

```
CMD powershell C:\\src\\curl.exe -f http://127.0.0.1:8080/health; if($LastExitCode) {exit 1}
```

Comment: and by "crap OS" you obviously mean the OS you don't know anything about

Comment: know enough to tell that aside gaming, it's useless :)

Comment: yeah well, obviously, if you use something like powershell into curl you are a pretty creative person, you should get a mac for yourself to feel better

Comment: Nah Mac OS is probably no better than Windows. The only reasonable OS for a developer to work is naturally linux. Btw... If you happen to have a better solution my ears are all yours. I used curl since it is small and works perfectly on linux. Besides this way windows containers will be more consistent with what we have on linux ones... but as I said - please enlighten me, instead criticizing. How can I do this better?

Comment: just use powershell cmdlet? `invoke-webrequest`? it even has an alias of `curl` specifically made for people using only the best OS in the world. Btw, I'm using Windows + Bash on WIndows which is a strictly better setup than plain Linux for obvious reasons

Comment: Containers are based on nanoserver and most of commands are inaccessible, but I'll check this one. Thanks. What about changing error code? Basically I need 0 when it's 200 and 1 otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD powershell -command `  
    try { `
     $response = iwr http://localhost; `
     if ($response.StatusCode -eq 200) { return 0} `
     else {return 1}; `
    } catch { return 1 }
```

Found this on the [web](https://blog.sixeyed.com/docker-healthchecks-why-not-to-use-curl-or-iwr/), perhaps of any use if you don't want to use or have curl.

Answer (score 2):

This is a correct Healthcheck tested *(in Powershell you need to use "exit" and not "return")*.

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD powershell -command `  
try { `
 $response = iwr http://localhost; `
 if ($response.StatusCode -eq 200) { exit 0 } `
 else { exit 1 }; `
} catch { exit 1 }
```

Documentation : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck

Comment: Good point with `exit` instead of `return`. Easily verifiable with `powershell -Command "return 5" ; "Exit Code: $LastExitCode"` vs. `powershell -Command "exit 5" ; "Exit Code: $LastExitCode"`.